# Browsing in TAGS screen

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Suggestion when you are browsing in the tags screen:

When you select a TAG, and then a question, when you press back button, back to select TAG again when should be to the questions about the TAG you selected previously as you do on the other options.

Comment: Yes! but It is not fixed. Regards.

Comment: But not exactly the some. It is similar, but different suggestion.

Comment: Your question says you should return to the question list rather than the tag page no?

Comment: When you are in the Stack Overflow, and select Tags, appear a list with all the tags, ok, when you select a TAG, let say Android, you see all the question filtered by this TAG, and when you select a question, when you press back from the question, return to the tag secreen again and not to the questions about the tag you selected. But to sumarize is what you say, yes.

Comment: Sure, that's what the other question is saying. It's not a new issue and has been asked a lot before (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/264248?lq=1 for more)

Comment: You are right. Sorry then.

Comment: No need to apologise, it's a valid request, there's not really any active development on the Android app though so not likely it will be fixed any time soon

Comment: Ok. Now, Stack overflow suggest "That solved my problem", but really it is not solve the navigation problem, and the other option is "No, my question is different", so What I should I do?

Comment: One of the most common android app bug reports/feature requests. Sadly enough, it will never be done